# Scraping data from multiple Highcharts charts using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, highcharts

I am trying to use python (selenium) to extract the data from all the RSPO CREDITS highcharts into a pandas `dataframe` with Name of chart, Year, Month, and values (No of credits and Price (USD)) on https://rspo.org/palmtrace and have been looking at some other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165122/scraping-high-charts-data-trouble-scraping-all-data-points-in-chart) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864796/how-to-scrape-charts-from-a-website-with-python) to do this. However, it looks like these charts are formatted a bit differently so any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your site has two 22-series charts and two 16-series charts, a rough solution would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

website = "https://rspo.org/palmtrace"

driver.get(website)
time.sleep(2)

my_data = []

for chart in range(2):
    for series in range(22):
        temp = driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[{}]'
                                '.series[{}].options.data'.format(chart,series))
        temp.insert(0, driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[{}]'
                                '.series[{}].options.name'.format(chart,series)))
        my_data.append(temp)

for chart in range(2,4):
    for series in range(16):
        temp = driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[{}]'
                                '.series[{}].options.data'.format(chart,series))
        temp.insert(0, driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[{}]'
                                '.series[{}].options.name'.format(chart,series)))
        my_data.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Do you know how I can pull the values out into a pandas `dataframe`? I updated my question to reflect this

Comment: Have edited my code now.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't include the chart title, year, and month. Do you know how I can have those appended to the `data frame` as well?

Comment: Have added the years. Months are the columns. 1st chart is the first 22 lines, 2nd chart is the next 22 lines, 3rd chart is the next 16 lines, 4th is the rest.